# Using CDO to send using HTML Body in IIS7.5 and classic ASP

Tags: email, asp-classic, cdo.message

We are using the following script. It works fine if we call HTML/ASP from another URL but if we attempt to send mail from the domain the script is on the site times out and requires the application pool to be recycled.

The script also works if plain text is used and not HTML. 
Any ideas folks?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Dim objCDO
Set objCDO = Server.CreateObject ("CDO.Message")

objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "127.0.0.1"
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25 
objCDO.Configuration.Fields.Update

objCDO.Subject = "XYZ Order"
objCDO.From = "all@xyz.co.uk"
objCDO.To = "user@user.com"
'objCDO.TextBody = "TEST E-MAIL"
objCDO.CreateMHTMLBody "http://www.xyz.co.uk/zzzHTML.asp"

objCDO.Send
Set objCDO = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Can you ping your domain from the server sending the email?

Comment: Have you tried changing the URL at objCDO.CreateMHTMLBody "http://www.xyz.co.uk/zzzHTML.asp" to just something like google.com to eliminate that script as a possible cause?

Comment: Do you have remote desktop access, and if you can you view your site with a browser on the server itself?

Comment: that's easy your webserver does not have Internet access

Comment: @ulluoink - That would have been my conclusion six months ago.  However I've recently come across a situation where a server can access anything else on the internet but it can't see the sites it hosts itself, at least not via their public urls.  It's something to do with IP address configurations and the fact that the server is a virtual machine

Comment: Andy, yes I can ping.

John and Ulluoink, yes the server can see online and it will show the sites hosted locally. The server is a dedicated box and not a virtual one.